# Get an integer from a plist for Objective-C iPhone dev

Tags: objective-c, plist

I have the following DataAll.plist:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>ID</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Inigo Montoya</string>
    </dict>
  ....
</array>
```

I want to get the ID value from it.  My code gets the Name correctly, but the ID is a weird value.  Here's what I'm doing:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"DataAll" ofType:@"plist"];

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
self.allData = array;
[array release];

NSDictionary *first = [[NSDictionary alloc]
        initWithDictionary:[self.allData objectAtIndex:0]];

Data *firstData = [[Data alloc] init];

[firstData setData:first];

labelName.text = [firstData EXName];
labelID.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[firstData EXID]];
[firstData release];
```

Here's my Data.h

```
@interface Data : NSObject {
    NSNumber    *EXID;
    NSString    *EXName;
}
@property (readwrite, retain) NSNumber *EXID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *EXName;
```

And Data.m

```
@implementation Data
@synthesize EXID;
@synthesize EXName;

- (void) setData: (NSDictionary *) dictionary {
   self.EXName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];
   NSNumber *ID = [dictionary objectForKey:@"ID"];
   self.EXID = ID;
}
```

Many thanks in advance!  This is my first post, so I apologize if formatting isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[firstData EXID]];
```

EXID is an `NSNumber*` object and not an `int` so %d isn't what you want.  You need to either replace %d with %@ or unwrap the integer from the NSNumber by calling `[EXID integerValue]` or `[EXID intValue]`.  Which return `NSInteger` and `int` respectively.

Comment: Thanks so much wm_eddie! %@ did work (duh), but I also took your suggestion and went with an NSInteger instead of NSNumber*.

Answer (score 0):

Just because your data is in the plist as an integer doesn't mean it is retrieved as one. At least not when you retrieve with `[dict objectForKey:]`. Furthermore, `NSNumber` and `integer` are not the same data type.

My guess is the latter is throwing you off. That is to say the implicit conversion to `NSNumber`. Add the following before you call `setData` and update your OP with the output.

```
NSLog(@"plist entry: %@", first);
```

Comment: plist entry: { ID = 1; Name="Inigo Montoya;" } What does this tell me?  Thanks for speedy reply, btw.

Comment: @wm_eddie has identified the exact problem. My suggestion would be to change `EXID` and make it an `NSInteger` or simply an `int`.